# How wide should a webpage get?

Tags: website-design, responsive-design

So when creating a responsive design, how big should the maximum width of the container be?

- Should the maximum width of a webpage be fixed ([`width: 100%; max-width: 1200px`](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvcxg/))?
- Should it grow slower after the last breakpoint ([`width: 100%; max-width: calc(600px + 40%)`](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvcxg/1/))? If so, how fast should it grow (20%, 40%, 60%)?
- Or should it go full-width, always ([`width: 100%`](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvcxg/2/))?

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad and dependant of circumstances, we could say, always use 100% to use al the space, or 80% so you give some room and more space, or 90% but no more that xxx pixels if you are going to do..., etc If you can describe the reason or content of the page, it's easier to narrow down the answer, give as much information as possible.

Comment: @PatomaS I didn't have anything specific in mind here, but let's assume that it's a has a lot of text, like a blog. Or an SE site.

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of [this earlier question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/42828/11687). As noted in that issue; it depends on the content. Since you mentioned long-form text content, you should probably also read [this question about maximum line-length](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/3618/11687).

Comment: @Kit [This](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/42830/42756) seems pretty vague… you can make it big, but it depends on content. The question is more vague than this: "what should the width be?", not "what should the max-width be?". The second link is helpful.

Comment: I accept that it's vague, but that's the nature of the beast, sadly. The question of what size is appropriate for your content is always going to be meaningless without seeing your content and understanding the problem you're trying to solve. It's a bit like asking "what font size should my headings be"?

Comment: @Kit Can't there still be a "90% of people will die when they see a 500px fixed-width website" number?

Comment: I think the best you'll find is the max line length debate. There's more to it than that, though; there are people who feel that every pixel not dedicated to content is a waste of their hardware—high information density makes them feel special/elite. Some users use a big screen because it allows them to have the font size much larger to help with poor eyesight. Some use a big screen because they want to do lots of things at once. Normally a big screen means the user is further away so there's a font size implication too. It all comes down to "what behaviour would most benefit my users?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of your website should be relative to your content needs and the user's viewport. Sometimes that means limiting the size of website to XX pixels. Sometimes that means a 100% width.

A big issue is line length. Copy lines should be [45-75 characters long, with 66-characters regarded as the ideal.](http://webtypography.net/2.1.2) If you cap you lines to that size, yet have a base font-size of 14pt, long blocks of copy are going to fill lost among a lot of negative space. To counter this you can increase your font-size to 18 or 21pt. Yet even there though you can't go too much larger because your vertical height will start to be too large. Which means users will have to scroll more.

Just remember that if you're making your website 100%, you need to scale things accordingly - not just the grid. Making your website's layout responsive is important, but that's just a facet of RWD. Making your content scale accordingly is more important.

Answer (score 1):

A web page ideal width is the relative size 100 percent. It would make a great opportunity for you and your design team to work on mobile friendly or responsive design. It a tough approach since you have to address screen that are extremely wide, but implemented correct it is your best option.

In detail you can add left and right padding, add another column when viewport expands, or whatever your design team finds pleasing. The same idea works when the viewport gets smaller; move a column, decrease padding…

[image]

Comment: That's what I was thinking. On a huge monitor, the puny  [1kpx of SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout) doesn't suffice. And large margins are welcome (at least I like it). I guess the huge line length problem can be solved by using a complex grid with small tiles, large margins, and large(r) text.

Comment: Just wondering: in the very wide view layout padding between columns/cells is not going to help to reduce the line length of the wide text portion. Adding or increasing margins in this portion is going to mess up the (perceived) grid. So what can you to restrict the width of all text blocks to a readable length apart from page margins? The only thing I can think of is to have columns within the wide text block, but that can really mess up the read experience with longer texts, as you would have to scroll up and down to go from one column to the next. Please help my foggy brain here...

Comment: @MarjanVenema If you want to limit line width to 80 characters, you need to add more columns or increase padding. You can always have fixed width on columns and add/remove columns based on viewport width.

Comment: Ok, I guess I am hypothesizing a bit, but what if, in your big/wide example, the site simply doesn't have any more blocks of content to shift around and the viewport still gets wider. Would you then shift the content blocks in the top content row down to the left or right of the wide content block? Could work I suppose.

Comment: @MarjanVenema No, not really. I'd keep increasing margin/padding if the viewport expands further than 1900 px.

Comment: Ok, that would space out the top three blocks. But wouldn't doing that destroy alignment of the wide text block beneath them when you __also__ restrict the lines to a maximum for readable length? Either line lengths in the wide block would get too long, or you would need to introduce white space on its left or right which w/could make a mess of the nice alignment the blocks are showing in your example, unless you restrict increasing the padding to the page margins and the gutter between the gray/black and blue blocks? Try doing that in a standard grid system :)

Comment: @MarjanVenema: [Microsoft does that a lot in Metro (using multiple columns of text instead of one long one)](http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-81-tip-better-reading-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: @KitGrose: yes, and that is fine, __provided__ you ensure that there is no need for vertical scrolling (as well). Ever tried to read a pdf document with multiple columns where the pages are higher than your screen? It sucks.

Comment: @MarjanVenema not wrong!